# Find foreign key by primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to know a particular primary key used in how many tables as reference key or as simple column in database? Or vice versa? Please answer for heidisql or MySql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it is done:

```
use information_schema;

SELECT * from key_column_usage
WHERE referenced_table_name = 'table_name'  # table that contains the primary key
and 
referenced_column_name = 'id'; # the primary key in that table
```

This is going to give you a table that has all the details.

Comment: Since, the solution works, could you please accept the answer?

Comment: yes i had accepted the answer what next should i do ??

Comment: you can accept the answer by check the check mark, which is normally on top left of the answer. Here is a link that describe how to do this. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. Thanks for supporting the community.